# Debugger ignores the edited file

Tags: c++, edit, visual-studio-2015

Why doesn't 'Edit & Continue' feature work in VS2015?
The debugger will ignore the edit and you will see an error message when you continue execution and I get the following

> “The source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the
>   file used to build the application being debugged.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the Debug Information Format to be “Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)”. If this option is incorrectly set the debugger will ignore the edit, it will be just like modifying a file with edit and continue disabled.

If you make an edit in a binary not compiled with this option, the debugger will ignore the edit and you will see an error message when you continue execution “The source file has changed. It no longer matches the version of the file used to build the application being debugged.”

> Open the Property Pages of the project.
>
> Under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> set the Debug Information
> Format to “Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)”

Edit & Continue has only been introduced in VS2015, therefore this option is not available on earlier versions.